# html css outer div text align center, inside div text align left

Tags: html, css

there is a box with text, at the right of the box there is an image

The box of text is have z index higher than image, so box of text look like in front of image

I used text-align center, to center all components inside div, and this is a must

Now I want the only text, only the text in box of text is align left

How can I achieve this?

```css
.button-yellow, .button-red {
  font: 16px AdobeCaslonPro;
  text-decoration: none;  
  padding: 6px 12px 6px 12px;
  border-right: 1px solid #333333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
  border-radius: 4px;
  moz-border-radius: 4px;
  webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  font-style: italic;
}

.button-yellow {
  background-color: #ccb96b;
  color: #430615;
}

.button-red {
  background-color: #430615;
  color: #ccb96b;
  margin-top: -20px;
}

#section-welcome-content {
   text-align: center;
}

#welcome-content{
  width: 45%;
  margin:  0 0 0 0 ;
}

#welcome-content-inner {
  background-color: #ccb96b;
  color: #430615;
  padding: 50px;
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
}

#welcome-content p{
  
}

#crop {
  width: 600px;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin:  0 0 0 -50px ;
  
}

#crop img {
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
  margin: -75px 0 0 -100px;
  z-index: 1;
  
}
```

```html
<section id="section-welcome-content" class="pad">
<div id="welcome-content" style=" display: inline-block; " >
   <div id="welcome-content-inner" >
    <p>
    <h3 style="font-size: 1.5em; text-transform: uppercase;"> <i>Lorem ipsum</i> </h3>

     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris arcu sapien, dignissim id laoreet quis, sollicitudin sed dui. Mauris mauris ligula, hendrerit sed ligula vitae, viverra auctor eros. Duis rutrum dolor a felis elementum, eu facilisis justo sollicitudin. 
     <br><br>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris arcu sapien, dignissim id laoreet quis, sollicitudin sed dui. Mauris mauris ligula, hendrerit sed ligula vitae, viverra auctor eros. Duis rutrum dolor a felis elementum, eu facilisis justo sollicitudin. 
            <br><br><br>
    <a href="<?php echo base_url().$this->lang->lang(); ?>/aboutus" class="button-red" style="float: right;"> Read more</a>
    </p>
    </div>
  <div>
          &nbsp;
  </div>
  <div>
  &nbsp;
  </div>        
  </div>
      <div id="crop" style=" display: inline-block; ">
        <img src="http://media.caranddriver.com/images/media/51/2017-10best-lead-photo-672628-s-original.jpg" alt="" style=" "/>
  </div>
  </section>
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: buddy do not mind,but your question was like ChristopherNolan movies to me. To make it simple, can you upload an image showing the output you want ? That would make it quick to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer comprises of 2 scenarios so it can help you the way you want. So you can choose the best way you want. I have also included live example so you can easily check it .

> **1. For all text inside  to be on left, which includes both heading and text. Add this css**

```
/* For All Left */

#welcome-content-inner {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```css
.button-yellow,
.button-red {
  font: 16px AdobeCaslonPro;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 6px 12px 6px 12px;
  border-right: 1px solid #333333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
  border-radius: 4px;
  moz-border-radius: 4px;
  webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  font-style: italic;
}

.button-yellow {
  background-color: #ccb96b;
  color: #430615;
}

.button-red {
  background-color: #430615;
  color: #ccb96b;
  margin-top: -20px;
}

#section-welcome-content {
  text-align: center;
}

#welcome-content {
  width: 45%;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

#welcome-content-inner {
  background-color: #ccb96b;
  color: #430615;
  padding: 50px;
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
}

#welcome-content p {}

#crop {
  width: 600px;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 0 0 -50px;
}

#crop img {
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
  margin: -75px 0 0 -100px;
  z-index: 1;
}


/* For All Left */

#welcome-content-inner {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<section id="section-welcome-content" class="pad">
  <div id="welcome-content" style=" display: inline-block; ">
    <div id="welcome-content-inner">
      <p>
        <h3 style="font-size: 1.5em; text-transform: uppercase;"> <i>Lorem ipsum</i> </h3>

        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris arcu sapien, dignissim id laoreet quis, sollicitudin sed dui. Mauris mauris ligula, hendrerit sed ligula vitae, viverra auctor eros. Duis rutrum dolor a felis elementum, eu facilisis justo
        sollicitudin.
        <br><br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris arcu sapien, dignissim id laoreet quis, sollicitudin sed dui. Mauris mauris ligula, hendrerit sed ligula vitae, viverra auctor eros. Duis rutrum dolor a felis elementum,
        eu facilisis justo sollicitudin.
        <br><br><br>
        <a href="<?php echo base_url().$this->lang->lang(); ?>/aboutus" class="button-red" style="float: right;"> Read more</a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div>
      &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div>
      &nbsp;
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="crop" style=" display: inline-block; ">
    <img src="http://media.caranddriver.com/images/media/51/2017-10best-lead-photo-672628-s-original.jpg" alt="" style=" " />
  </div>
</section>
```

> **2. For only text to be on left and heading on center. Add this css.**

```
/* For only text Left and heading center */

#welcome-content-inner {
  text-align: left;
}

#welcome-content-inner h3 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```css
.button-yellow,
.button-red {
  font: 16px AdobeCaslonPro;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 6px 12px 6px 12px;
  border-right: 1px solid #333333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
  border-radius: 4px;
  moz-border-radius: 4px;
  webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  font-style: italic;
}

.button-yellow {
  background-color: #ccb96b;
  color: #430615;
}

.button-red {
  background-color: #430615;
  color: #ccb96b;
  margin-top: -20px;
}

#section-welcome-content {
  text-align: center;
}

#welcome-content {
  width: 45%;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

#welcome-content-inner {
  background-color: #ccb96b;
  color: #430615;
  padding: 50px;
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
}

#welcome-content p {}

#crop {
  width: 600px;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 0 0 -50px;
}

#crop img {
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
  margin: -75px 0 0 -100px;
  z-index: 1;
}


/* For only text Left and heading center */

#welcome-content-inner {
  text-align: left;
}

#welcome-content-inner h3 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section id="section-welcome-content" class="pad">
  <div id="welcome-content" style=" display: inline-block; ">
    <div id="welcome-content-inner">
      <p>
        <h3 style="font-size: 1.5em; text-transform: uppercase;"> <i>Lorem ipsum</i> </h3>

        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris arcu sapien, dignissim id laoreet quis, sollicitudin sed dui. Mauris mauris ligula, hendrerit sed ligula vitae, viverra auctor eros. Duis rutrum dolor a felis elementum, eu facilisis justo
        sollicitudin.
        <br><br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris arcu sapien, dignissim id laoreet quis, sollicitudin sed dui. Mauris mauris ligula, hendrerit sed ligula vitae, viverra auctor eros. Duis rutrum dolor a felis elementum,
        eu facilisis justo sollicitudin.
        <br><br><br>
        <a href="<?php echo base_url().$this->lang->lang(); ?>/aboutus" class="button-red" style="float: right;"> Read more</a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div>
      &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div>
      &nbsp;
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="crop" style=" display: inline-block; ">
    <img src="http://media.caranddriver.com/images/media/51/2017-10best-lead-photo-672628-s-original.jpg" alt="" style=" " />
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add `text-align:left;` in your `welcome-content-inner` **div** and you're there.

```css
.button-yellow, .button-red {
  font: 16px AdobeCaslonPro;
  text-decoration: none;  
  padding: 6px 12px 6px 12px;
  border-right: 1px solid #333333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
  border-radius: 4px;
  moz-border-radius: 4px;
  webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  font-style: italic;
}

.button-yellow {
  background-color: #ccb96b;
  color: #430615;
}

.button-red {
  background-color: #430615;
  color: #ccb96b;
  margin-top: -20px;
}

#section-welcome-content {
   text-align: center;
}

#welcome-content{
  width: 45%;
  margin:  0 0 0 0 ;
}

#welcome-content-inner {
  background-color: #ccb96b;
  color: #430615;
  padding: 50px;
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
}

#welcome-content p{
  
}

#crop {
  width: 600px;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin:  0 0 0 -50px ;
  
}

#crop img {
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
  margin: -75px 0 0 -100px;
  z-index: 1;
  
}
```

```html
  <section id="section-welcome-content" class="pad">
      <div id="welcome-content" style=" display: inline-block; " >
        <div id="welcome-content-inner" >
          <p>
            <h3 style="font-size: 1.5em; text-transform: uppercase;"> <i>Lorem ipsum</i> </h3>

            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris arcu sapien, dignissim id laoreet quis, sollicitudin sed dui. Mauris mauris ligula, hendrerit sed ligula vitae, viverra auctor eros. Duis rutrum dolor a felis elementum, eu facilisis justo sollicitudin. 
            <br><br>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris arcu sapien, dignissim id laoreet quis, sollicitudin sed dui. Mauris mauris ligula, hendrerit sed ligula vitae, viverra auctor eros. Duis rutrum dolor a felis elementum, eu facilisis justo sollicitudin. 
            <br><br><br>
            <a href="<?php echo base_url().$this->lang->lang(); ?>/aboutus" class="button-red" style="float: right;"> Read more</a>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div>
          &nbsp;
        </div>
        <div>
          &nbsp;
        </div>        
      </div>
      <div id="crop" style=" display: inline-block; ">
        <img src="http://media.caranddriver.com/images/media/51/2017-10best-lead-photo-672628-s-original.jpg" alt="" style=" "/>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Hope it helps.